# Не могу вызвать onResponse в retrofit, все время вызывается onFailure

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Вот мой сервис ретрофита

```
class NetworkService private constructor() {
private val mRetrofit: Retrofit

interface APIService {
    @GET("/search")
    fun getAlbums(@QueryMap map: Map<String, String>): Call<List<Albums>>
}
val aPI: APIService
    get() = mRetrofit.create(APIService::class.java)

companion object {
    private var mInstance: NetworkService? = null
    private const val BASE_URL = "https://itunes.apple.com"

    //Singleton for class
    val instance: NetworkService?
        get() {
            if (mInstance == null) {
                mInstance = NetworkService()
            }
            return mInstance
        }
}

init {
    mRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}
```

}

Я получаю даныне в searchacticity и сразу вывожу результат. С POJO все в порядке, они сенерированы с помощью сервиса
Вот searchactivity

```
class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var recyclerView:RecyclerView
lateinit var adapter:SearchRecyclerViewAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search)
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewTable)
    handleIntent(intent)

}
@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
    handleIntent(intent)
}

private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH == intent.action) {
        val query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY)
        doMySearch(query!!)
    }
}
private fun doMySearch(query: String) {
      val lang:String
      val r3 = Regex ("[а-я]+", RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
      lang = if (r3.matches(query) ){
          "ru_ru"
      } else {
          "en_us"
      }
    val data: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    data["term"] = query
    data["entity"] = "album"
    data["attribute"] = "albumTerm"
    data["lang"] = lang
      NetworkService.instance?.aPI?.getAlbums(data)?.enqueue(object: Callback<List<Albums>> {
          override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Albums>>, response: Response<List<Albums>>) {
              val album =response.body()
              recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@SearchActivity)
              adapter = SearchRecyclerViewAdapter(this@SearchActivity, album!!)
              recyclerView.adapter = adapter
          }

          override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Albums>>, t: Throwable) {
              Toast.makeText(this@SearchActivity, "Error ocurred by getting request", 
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
          }
      })
}
```

}
НЕ могу понять в чем ошибка, я делал так раньше и все работало

Comment: Выведите в логи ошибку, которая у вас возникает. С вероятностью 97.4% сразу станет понятно что не так. Если не станет - добавьте лог ошибки в вопрос - подскажем что не так

Comment: Ошибки нету, вызывается метод onFailure, а хотелось бы onResponse)

Comment: Ошибка точно есть. 100%. Просто вы её в логи не выводите. Добавьте в onFailure строку, которая в логи выведет ошибку. И это всегда надо делать, когда у вас есть переменная с типом ошибки - иначе вы не сможете находить ошибки в логах. `t.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Спасибо, нашел ошибку. Проблема была в том, что Moshi ожидал json array, а получал object
 Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path$
Нужно было вместо List<Albums> отправлять ALbums в callback